# Getting CMake to give an error/warning about unreferenced symbols

Tags: cmake

I'm wondering how I would go about making CMake produce an error, or at least a warning, when the linker cannot find symbols that are referenced in a source file?

For example, let's say I have foo.c:

```
#include "bar.h" //bar.h provides bar()

void foo(void)
{
  bar()
  return;
}
```

In the case that I am building a static library, if i am not smart about how i have used my add_library() directive, the default behavior seems to be to not even give a warning that  bar is an unreferenced symbols in foo's object archive file (.a)

Comment: That's the linker's job - CMake isn't designed to parse C or C++, so it won't be able to reliably help with this.

Comment: You are correct! I've done some more research, and I agree.

Answer (score 4):

The `CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS` compiler flags for building shared libraries should get the compiler to do what you want.

`set(CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS "-Wl,--no-undefined")`
On Unix systems, this will make the linker report any unresolved symbols from object files (which is quite typical when you compile many targets in CMake projects, but do not bother with linking target dependencies in proper order).

Source: http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_Useful_Variables

Answer (score 0):

There's the `-z now` for the GCC linker these days, but yeah, this isn't CMake's problem.

The most fool-proof way I've found only works on shared libraries, but what you do is basically write a test for each shared library and it then just does `dlopen(path, RTLD_NOW)` (and similar for Windows) and then use its return value as the test return value. To get a list of all shared objects, I have a wrapper function around `add_library` which adds all shared libraries to a global property which then is used to generate the tests dynamically. I remember there being some way to tell if a target was shared or static, but I'm not finding it the docs right now.